# Get value from file - php

Tags: php, strpos

Let's say I have this in my text file:

```
Author:MJMZ
Author URL:http://abc.co
Version: 1.0
```

How can I get the string "MJMZ" if I look for the string "Author"?

I already tried the solution from another question ([Php get value from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393369/php-get-value-from-text-file)) but with no success.

The problem may be because of the `strpos` function. In my case, the word "Author" got two. So the strpos function can't solve my problem.

Comment: Instead of searching for `Author` why not search for `Author:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split each line at the `:` using `explode`, then check if the prefix matches what you're searching for:

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($prefix, $data) = explode(':', $line);
    if (trim($prefix) == "Author") {
        echo $data;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents('myfilename.ext');
preg_match('/^Author\s*\:\s*([^\r\n]+)/', $file_contents, $matches);
$code = isset($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 'no-code-found';

echo $code;
```

Now the $matches variable should contains the MJMZ.

The above, will search for the first instance of the `Author:CODE_HERE` in your file, and will place the `CODE_HERE` in the `$matches` variable.

More specific, the regex. will search for a string that starts with the word `Author` followed with an optional space `\s*`, followed by a semicolon character `\:`, followed by an optional space `\s*`, followed by one or more characters that it is not a new line `[^\r\n]+`.

Answer (score 0):

If your file will have dinamically added items, then you can sort it into array.

```
$content = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
$line = explode("\n", $content);
$item = new Array();
foreach($line as $l){
    $var = explode(":", $l);
    $value = "";

    for($i=1; $i<sizeof($var); $i++){
        $value .= $var[$i];
    }

    $item[$var[0]] = $value;
}
// Now you can access every single item with his name:
print $item["Author"];
```

The for loop inside the foreach loop is needed, so you can have multiple "**:**" in your list. The program will separate name from value at the first "**:**"

Answer (score 0):

First take lines from file, convert to array then call them by their keys.

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
$pieces = explode(":", $line);
$array[$pieces[0]] = $pieces[1];
 }
} else {
// error opening the file.
} 
fclose($handle);
echo $array['Author'];
```